# How to add plugin's "ftplugin"

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ftplugin

I often see Vim plugin have own "ftplugin" directory.
(for example: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim)

How to load these ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Those files are automatically loaded by Vim when needed (file type used). It is part of the program logic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set runtimepath to folder that contain rust.vim.

You can set it manually (:set rtp+=path/to/folder)or user plugin manager like: Vim-plug,Vundle.....

:help runtimepath or :h rtp  - for detailed help

:set rtp? - to see all runtimepaths